# ng-if slow on element with transitions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-transitions

I'm with angular 1.4, and i hope this one is a common, and solvable problem:

I have an div with background image of a ball, the div has the following extra styling:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

Because the ball moves left and right with a smoothing transition (the one from the style).
When i ng-if this div to false, when it needs to disappear, the div is stuck there for a sec (or half a sec?), is there any way around this behaviour?

It's not a matter of $digest or $apply, and without the transitions it goes away quickly and normaly.

Comment: You can maybe try to remove the class that has this transition when you change to ng-if false. Might help, not sure though.

Comment: tried using ng-class and put this class only when ng-if is true, not the answer im afraid

Comment: Maybe switch ng-if with ng-show, or try to set visibility: hidden instead?